# Apostol Calculus - what does axiom 6 of area mean

Tags: calculus, area

The axiom is given in this picture:=

[image]

I actually have lot of questions from this topic but I post only one here: What does axiom 6 actually mean? Can only one real number lie in a interval $[a(S), a(T)]$?

Also can only one number lie in $(a(S), a(T))$ ?

Comment: Even allowing for the distortions from conversion to a picture, that is a horrible example of typography run amok.

Comment: @Paul Apologies everywhere I found only this copy of apostol, its almost as it was in the pdfs

Comment: You don't have to apologize for something that wasn't your doing (though learning mathjax so that you can format it yourself in the future is advisable). I was just so appalled at the pointless variation in fonts used that I felt compelled to comment on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Infinitely many real numbers lie in an interval such as $[a(S), a(T)]$ for a given $S$ and $T$, but that is not what the axiom is referring to. Note that the axiom says "... for all step regions $S$ and $T$ satisfying (1.1)..." So there are infinitely many $S$ and $T$ to consider. Only one real number lies in all those infinitely many intervals.

As an example, consider the intervals

$$\left[1-\frac 1n, 1+\frac 1n\right]$$

where $n$ is a positive integer. Then for any particular value of $n$ there are infinitely many real numbers in that interval. However, only one real number, namely $1$, lies in all of those intervals.

Comment: Nice example ! And the *intention* of Axiom 6 is to allow areas to be derived by the method of exhaustion. For example, if we can only directly calculate the areas of triangles, rectangles and other regions bounded by straight lines then we need Axiom 6 to derive the area of a circle (be enclosing it between polygons with increasing numbers of sides).

Comment: Oh so this means that we consider infinite or any number of regions $S,T$ such that $S\subseteq Q\subseteq T$ but only $Q$ is common to all choices...

Comment: @jeea: There may or may not be other sets other than $Q$ (let's call one $Q'$) such that $S\subseteq Q'\subseteq T$ for those $S$ and $T$ that follow the given restrictions. There is only one real number $c$ that fits in the intervals $[a(S),a(T)]$. In measure theory, $Q$ and $Q'$ would differ by a set of measure zero. These definitions need to cover truly weird sets. You may cover some of those weird sets later in your studies. Is that clear?

Comment: I dont fully understand last point, maybe Q' contains some more points, anyway area axioms have that points have measure zero. So Q and Q' will have same measure here?

Comment: @jeea: Yes, exactly. $Q$ and $Q'$ may both fit between all the $S$s and $T$s but that doesn't matter since the points that are in one set but not the other are so few that they have zero area. Finitely many points definitely have zero area. There are some collections of infinitely many points that also have zero area. The point is that the area between the $S$s and $T$s is pinned down to only one value, even if the exact set $Q$ is not.